# how to down load PDF file and save it in ipad BD via XML parsing

Tags: ipad

I am new in iPhone/i Pad development andi have problem in. How to Download pdf file in ipad.
i have URL of pdf and i need to download it. and used it offline..
Can any one help me to sole the problem.

thnx in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSData *yourPDFFileData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:yourPDFURL]];

//Store the Data locally as PDF File

NSString *docPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle]  resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"PDFFiles"]];

NSString *yourFilePath = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourPDFName.pdf"];

[yourPDFFileData writeToFile:yourFilePath atomically:YES];
```

This will save your file from URL to local iPhone/iPad. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Muhammed Did this resolve your problem ? If yes please mark this as accepted so that it can be helpful to others if same issue is there.